# What is wrong with my binary search code?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void bi(int k,int l,int r,int arr[]){
    int m=r-l/2;
    if(arr[m]==k)
    {
        cout<<"found at"<<m;
    }
    if(arr[m]<k)
    {
        bi(k,m+1,r,arr);
    }
    if(arr[m]>k)
    {
        bi(k,l,m-1,arr);
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"enter size of array";
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    int k;
    cout<<"enter number to be searched";
    cin>>k;
    bi(k,0,n-1,arr);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works, but I saw on other websites they use `mid = l + (r - l) / 2;` why we can directly write `r-l/2`. And they also used `if(r<=l)`but code works without these two. I know it's very stupid easy question but I want to clear my basics.

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be sorted? It's a requirement for binary search.

Comment: Remember your operator precedence from basic math class... `r - l / 2` is equal to `r - (l / 2)`.

Comment: `r - l / 2` ... first time calling, `l` is `0`, so you're really setting `m=r` .. You're not doing a binary search. Also, what if the value isn't found? Infinite recursion.

Comment: `l + (r - l) / 2;` is the middle of the range, `(r+l)/2` is also, (but candidate to overflow). `r-l/2` is not (neither for `(r-l)/2` which is the half-range size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "bi" in "binary" comes from splitting the interval in two equally large intervals. Your code isnt doing that. To make it work it is not stricly necessary to have both same size, but it affects the resulting complexity depending on which side the result is. Also I am not sure if your intervals actually converge.

This `m`:

```
int m=r-l/2;
```

is not in the middle between `l` and `r`, but `mid = l + (r - l) / 2;` is.

> And they also used if(r<=l)but code works without these two.

Thats because your code assumes that the element is always present. Your code will not work if thats not the case. If the element is not present you will eventually reach `r <= l` but `arr[m]==k` is `false`. To stop the algorithm a stop condition ala

```
if (r <= l) return arr[l];
```

or

```
if (r <= l) throw "element not found";
```

is needed.